# Problem installing Epson 645 drivers related to lsb

Tags: drivers, printing

I previously had this working with Ubuntu 10.x, and just recently upgraded to 12.04 (64 bit).

I had installed the driver from Epson: epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.2.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb, and now also tried: epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.2.2-1lsb3.2_i386.deb but neither worked.

```
> sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.2.2-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
(Reading database ... 753018 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 1.2.2-1lsb3.2 (using epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.2.2-1lsb3.2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 ...
cups stop/waiting
cups start/running, process 28199
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386:
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 depends on lsb (>= 3.2).
dpkg: error processing epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386
```

The issue seems to be:
epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 depends on lsb (>= 3.2).

I have lsb 4.0 installed, but maybe it's not the i386 version?

```
> dpkg -l | grep lsb
iU  epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386                          1.2.2-1lsb3.2                                   Epson Inkjet Printer Driver (ESC/P-R) for Linux
ii  lsb                                                      4.0-0ubuntu20.2                                 Linux Standard Base 4.0 support package
ii  lsb-base                                                 4.0-0ubuntu20.2                                 Linux Standard Base 4.0 init script functionality
ii  lsb-core                                                 4.0-0ubuntu20.2                                 Linux Standard Base 4.0 core support package
ii  lsb-cxx                                                  4.0-0ubuntu20.2                                 Linux Standard Base 4.0 C++ support package
ii  lsb-desktop                                              4.0-0ubuntu20.2                                 Linux Standard Base 4.0 Desktop support package
ii  lsb-graphics                                             4.0-0ubuntu20.2                                 Linux Standard Base 4.0 graphics support package
ii  lsb-printing                                             4.0-0ubuntu20.2                                 Linux Standard Base 4.0 Printing package
ii  lsb-release                                              4.0-0ubuntu20.2                                 Linux Standard Base version reporting utility
```

I have also run `sudo apt-get -f install` to no avail.

This was for the "[Download Printer Driver  ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver)](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=19825&DSCCHK=5c7b4ff541de9a525dc84fb439258ab38e7fefd2)"

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had exactly the same problem. However I found this link :

http://www.muktware.com/news/976/ubuntu-becomes-first-os-get-automatic-epson-printer-drivers#.UK4l-eB2MUQ

which suggests that Ubuntu 12.04 is capable of finding and installing printer drivers automatically. Although sceptical, I decided to try with my wirelessly-connected Epson PX730WD.  It worked !  I used "System Settings / Printing / Add Printer / Find Printer" (roughly speaking) which found the printer as soon as I turned it on. In fact the drivers it found were for a slightly lower spec device - the PX710W - but so far I have not had any difficulties as a result of this.

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: It did work! I was skeptical because it had already listed the printer (but perhaps this was due to the USB cable). When I added it from the network it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On newer versions of Ubuntu (and amd64 Epson drivers), you only need to enable the Universe repository to install the dependencies.

For those who are not strictly on Ubuntu but another Debian derivative distribution: I downloaded an `lsb-compat` forward-port package from an MX Linux forum [from here](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?f=104&t=55746&hilit=lsb%20compat#p555628). You may be able to use this on Ubuntu if you do not want to enable the Universe repository.

That provided `lsb` for me and I was able to install the `epson-inkjet-printer-scpr` and the `epson-printer-utility` packages obtained from Epson. Shame on the printer manufacturers that they make us go through such hoops.

For the record I'm using [Devuan](https://devuan.org/) Ceres, so I'm not with Linux Mint. Devuan is a Debian derivative.

Comment: Yeah, last time I installed epson print drivers, I think I downloaded the [debian version](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=lsb-compat&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) or  I may have used an old Ubuntu version from https://packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: @mchid Thanks for the info, next time I'll look at that because a genuine repo based package seems like a better idea than a custom one.