# how to recompress a .deb package

Tags: package-management, deb, archive

I have a .deb file that needed to be altered. I have decompressed the .deb file and made the necessary changes.

How do I re-compress the file back into a .deb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

First, right click on the extracted archive and choose compress. Choose "tar.gz" format.

Next, in a terminal, run the following command:

```
sudo alien --to-deb ~/Desktop/filename.tar.gz
```

replacing ~/Desktop/filename.tar.gz with the actual path to the actual file.

Comment: So we know that the compression is tar.gz and you modified a deb file, why cannot you just change the tar.gz extension back to deb, why would you need alien?

Comment: Hmmm. I think --to-deb is to convert rpm or other packages to deb. Tar.gz as a package is the style of Slackware, but that doesn't have the deb structure. So I don't know how this worked for you.

Comment: @CsabaToth If I remember correctly, you cannot just change the extension or you will get an error. Also, I tested this at the time and it worked converting a tar.gz to deb. If you have another method, please answer and I will upvote if it works.

Comment: @CsabaToth I think you can use `dpkg-deb` but at the time I couldn't find any examples and had never used it before so I just used `alien` which I was already familiar with and it worked.

Comment: Yea, the simple extension change didn't work. The meta data files also cite lengths by bytes, so I'd need to recalculate those, but I got error messages left and right and was even not able to make it fix by `alien` because that errored with nonsense error messages as well. I went an alternative route to solve my printer driver problem https://askubuntu.com/a/1275435/180266 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609579/43406

Comment: @CsabaToth It's been a long time but it looks like I may have missed a step. I'm not sure if I selected the three files (extracted archive) or if there was a single directory. I'll have to try this again and provide some better instructions and use commands for the whole process to make it easier. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Don't worry, I moved on and you could be right.

Answer (score 1):

The primary command to manipulate deb packages is [dpkg-deb](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/dpkg/dpkg-deb.1.en.html).

To unpack the package, create an empty directory and switch to it, then run `dpkg-deb -R` to extract its control information and the package files. Use `dpkg-deb -b` to rebuild the package.

```
mkdir tmp
dpkg-deb -R original.deb tmp
# edit files
dpkg-deb -b tmp fixed.deb
```

Beware that unless your script is running as root, the files' permissions and ownership will be corrupted at the extraction stage.

For more info, see the original [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138190).